# Question about time evolution of a scalar field for the Källén-Lehmann formula proof

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, time-evolution, propagator

I'm going through the proof of the Källén-Lehmann formula in my professor's notes, and at one point he writes that, in the Heisenberg picture, we can write a real scalar field $\hat{\varphi}(t, \vec x)$ as
$$
\hat{\varphi}(t, \vec x) = e^{i\hat p x} \hat{\varphi}(0, \vec x) e^{-i\hat p x}
$$
so that when inserted in $\langle\Omega|\hat{\varphi}(t, \vec x)|n\rangle$ ($\Omega$ being the vacuum of the interation theory) we retreive the eigenvalues $p_n$. I don't understand why $\hat \varphi$ evolves in time with the momentum $\hat p$ in the exponential and not with the Hamiltonian $\hat H$, as the Heisenberg picture dictates.

EDIT: actually my prof wrote
$$
\hat \varphi(x) = e^{i\hat p x} \hat{\varphi}(0) e^{-i\hat p x}
$$
without being explicit about the time dependence. I'm not sure if this is just abuse of notation or actually makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the usual unitary transformation for translation in Quantum mechanics; see eg Sakurai. You can think of $x$ as a 4-vector $(t,\vec{x})$. Then, the last equation you wrote is just a translation along all coordinates. Note that along the time coordinate $x^0$, the generator $p^0$ IS the hamiltonian $H$(recall what $p^0$ means in special relativity). Along the spatial directions, the translation operator is the usual $\vec{p}=-i\nabla$.

So everything is consistent- time translation is generated by the Hamiltonian ($p^0$) while spatial translation is generated by $\vec{p}$. Note the power of a covariant formulation-you can encode all of this as the single operator  $e^{ix^\mu \hat{p}_\mu}$.